# How do I play a stream of H.264 NAL units in a video tag with MSE?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, h.264, media-source

The situation is pretty straight-forward; I am receiving a stream of NAL units via WebSockets.  How do I feed them into an HTML5 video tag using MSE?

Research indicates that I should mux the data into a fragmented mp4, but I haven't found any specifics on how to accomplish that.  Does anyone have specifics?

Comment: Can you reproduce example stream of NAL units?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Can you reproduce receiving stream of NAL units at plnkr https://plnkr.co ? Are the NAL units received as an `ArrayBuffer`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081377/unable-to-stream-video-over-a-websocket-to-firefox/

Comment: I don't think I could reproduce an example very easily; I'm receiving them from a private server.  Yes, I have them in an `ArrayBuffer`, parsed out of a blob.  Edit:  That link just demonstrates receiving mp4 data and playing it.  I'm receiving h.264 data and I need to mux it into mp4 (or something) in order to play it.

Comment: _"parsed out of a blob"_ Have you tried creating an `Blob URL` from `Blob` to set at `<video>` `src`? See   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157623/h264-video-works-using-src-attribute-same-video-fails-using-the-mediasource-api

Comment: Again, I don't have an mp4.  I have an h.264 stream, which, as far as I understand, is not directly playable by the browser without some other container.

Comment: If you have a `Blob`, you can use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL` of the stream at that point, to set as `src` of `<video>` element. You can mock a web socket communication to try; see link at second comment. Can you share the generated `ArrayBuffer`at plnkr, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle, stacksnippets or gist to try to reproduce stream?

Comment: @cbfoster [Video decoding in OSH JS Toolkit](https://opensensorhub.org/2016/09/16/video-decoding-in-osh-js-toolkit/)

Comment: *Again*, setting the stream source as the blob is only useful if the browser understands the data.  It's not mp4, webm, or ogg, and so it won't.  **I need to mux the h.264 data into mp4**.  Edit: Didn't see your newest link.  I'll take a look

Comment: you CAN"T. You must multiplex the elementary stream in some container like mp4.

Comment: ...about a year late, and the need to use a container like mp4 is stated directly in the original question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you receive a stream data e.g. hls, nalu h.264...and so on, you can transform and mux that into a fragmented mp4. Setting HTML5 video tag combines with MSE like creating mediaSource, mediaSource.addSourceBuffer, sourceBuffer.appendBuffer. That will play video while fmp4 right feed into buffer.

You may check out https://github.com/ChihChengYang/wfs.js which demonstrates transmuxing NALu h.264 streams from websocket. That works directly on top of a standard HTML5 element and MSE.